# "not all code paths return a value"

Tags: asp.net, xml, c#-4.0

```
namespace Electronic_Filing_of_Appeals
{
public class GenerateXML
{
  public ElectronicRecordAppellateCase CreateXml()
  {
```

My lies on the CreateXML() portion of this code. The error being kicked back is

> Electronic_Filing_of_Appeals.GenerateXML.CreateXml(): not all code paths return a value

I've tried different approached but the same result.

Any clue from the professionals?

Comment: Show the method itself, not just the definition...

Comment: It is not possible to tell from what you posted. The error means that there is a code path that doesn't return anything (missing `else`, `case` and the like).

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method is suppoed to return an instance of `ElectronicRecordAppellateCase` class. I guess you are returning the result in some **If** condition in your method or so like this.

```
public ElectronicRecordAppellateCase CreateXml()
{
  ElectronicRecordAppellateCase  output=new ElectronicRecordAppellateCase();
  if(someVariableAlreadyDefined>otherVariable)
  {
    //do something useful
    return output;
  }

 // Not returning anything if the if condition is not true!!!!

}
```

**Solution :** Make sure you are returning a valid return value from the method.

```
public ElectronicRecordAppellateCase CreateXml()
{
  ElectronicRecordAppellateCase  output=new ElectronicRecordAppellateCase();
  if(someVariableAlreadyDefined>otherVariable)
  {
    return output;
  } 
  return null;   //you can return the object here as needed
}
```

Comment: thank you all for the quick responses. I realized that I forgot my "return" at the end of my code. you all rock!

Answer (score 2):

If you specify output type, your method HAS to provide a value following every path of the code. When you see this error, it means one or more scenarios in your method don't return a value of a specified type, but result in a termination of the method instead.

This is an example of such problematic method:

```
public ElectronicRecordAppellateCase CreateXml()
{
    if (something)
    {
       return new ElectronicRecordAppellateCase();
    }
    // if the something is false, the method doesn't provide any output value!!!
}
```

This could be solved like this for instance:

```
public ElectronicRecordAppellateCase CreateXml()
{
    if (something)
    {
       return new ElectronicRecordAppellateCase();
    }
    else return null; // "else" isn't really needed here
}
```

See the pattern?

Answer (score 1):

not all code paths return value means, you function may not return a expected value

you don't show your code so I made a example

for example, the follow function has 3 paths, if parm equal 1, if parm equal 2 but if parm is not equal 1 or 2 don't return a value

```
function SomeObject foo(integer parm){

    if (parm == 1) {
        return new SomeObject();
    }
    if (parm == 2) {
        return new SomeObject();
    }
    //What if parm equal something else???
}
```